# Compile error inside boost: "use of undefined type 'boost::mpl::bool_<true>"

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

I am getting this strange error when compiling a large CPP file, at this line:

```
#include <boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp>
```

> Error C2027   use of undefined type
> 'boost::mpl::bool_'
> C:\github\microsoft\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex_parser.hpp 59

In bool_fwd.hpp I see:

```
typedef bool_<true> true_;
typedef bool_<false> false_;
```

In basic_regex_parser.hpp this is the line generating the error:

```
inline boost::intmax_t umax()
{
   return umax(mpl::bool_<std::numeric_limits<boost::intmax_t>::digits >= std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::digits>());
}
```

It appears `basic_regex_parser.hpp` isn't including `bool_fwd.hpp` but diving into these files I am lost what's wrong.

I've moved that #include to be right at the top of my `stdafx.h` file so it's before any other headers, and get the same result. We've recently switched from manually building boost 1.68 => 1.76 via vcpkg but I don't know which if either is the cause. We also switched to C++17 and I note boost has a dependency on `std::numeric_limits`, could this is the issue?

Comment: I am not sure _why_ we include this specific file... but I tested in a brand new project that does nothing else and get the same issue.

Comment: [Compiler Error C2027](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2027?view=msvc-160)A type cannot be used until it is defined. To resolve the error, be sure the type is fully defined before referencing it. I suggest you should add `#include <boost/mpl/bool_fwd.hpp>`

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT it just seems odd boost wouldn't include this itself so it concerns me I'd be masking a problem. If I change to simply `#include<boost/regex.hpp>` it builds but can't find explanation how that's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported, see same issue in https://github.com/boostorg/regex/issues/145